# Prevent browsers moving SVG elements around page breaks

Tags: html, css, printing, svg, rickshaw

I'm making a dashboard using SVG-based charts. When I print the page, the charts move around to prevent page breaks from happening within them. This is undesirable and breaks my layout but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

**Example:**

1. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eb8IRzLsW0V8vTVW1nJC?p=info)
2. Pop out preview
3. Print (just look at preview, don't actually have to print)

**Result:** 2 full boxes per page with uneven margins

**Expected:** 2.5ish boxes per page with even margins

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:** Here is a [gallery of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlqKV.jpg). Apparently this issue does not affect all browsers/Operating systems?

Comment: I get 3 boxes per page, and they fit very well.

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/a/lbwmI

Comment: Using `<div>` instead of `<svg>` it works ([demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/plIY2D0Nwqgezedb15Sc/preview)). I have checked `getComputedStyle` and there isn't any difference, so it seems it can't be fixed with CSS.

Comment: @Oriol I think the questions specifically demands `SVG` tag?

Comment: Yes, the Plunker is a simplification to remove variables. The actual use case in SVG-based charts using Rickshaw.

Comment: @ImranBughio That's why I posted that as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible.

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#allowed-page-breaks, these are the only cases in which an element can break between pages:

> In the normal flow, page breaks can occur at the following places:
>
> 1. In the vertical margin between block-level boxes. When an unforced page break occurs here, the used values of the relevant 'margin-top'
>      and 'margin-bottom' properties are set to '0'. When a forced page
>      break occurs here, the used value of the relevant 'margin-bottom'
>      property is set to '0'; the relevant 'margin-top' used value may
>      either be set to '0' or retained.
> 2. Between line boxes inside a block container box.
> 3. Between the content edge of a block container box and the outer edges of its child content (margin edges of block-level children or
>      line box edges for inline-level children) if there is a (non-zero) gap
>      between them.

You want (2), and you are getting (1).

The problem is that `<svg>` elements are replaced content.

And according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes, replaced elements aren't block container boxes:

> Except for table boxes, which are described in a later chapter, and
>   replaced elements, a block-level box is also a block container box.

That means that `<svg>` doesn't fulfill (2), so you can't get what you want.

Comment: Well shoot... Thanks for the detailed answer. I will award the bounty as soon as the system lets me (tomorrow). Cheers

Comment: in that case may be converting svg to img will help... this may require use of server-side php and stuff..

Comment: @ImranBughio But images are replaced content too :( See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element)

Comment: @anstosa Not I all, I hope I could have helped more. And thanks to you too for the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

I worked it around by applying `position: absolute` to parent container.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but when I set `position: absolute` on the `svg` itself, that worked!